# how to read xls file in Linux

Tags: linux, spreadsheet

I copied a .xls file from mail to server. when i opened it, it is in non-readable format. At the bottom i could see "[noeol][converted]"

I need to extract the data from xls file.

Answer (score 5):

If you're wanting to use the file from the command line, then locate and install `xls2csv` "reads MS-Excel file and puts its content as comma-separated data on standard output"

Alternatively, if you're wanting to open the file using a spreadsheet utility, try Apache OpenOffice.

- https://linux.die.net/man/1/xls2csv
- https://metacpan.org/pod/release/KEN/xls2csv-1.07/script/xls2csv
- https://www.openoffice.org/

Comment: Is there a similar program for XLSX files?

Answer (score 1):

The 'gnumeric' package comes with the ssconvert command line utility that can extract, convert xls files to many formats. It's also a spreadsheet software.
ssconvert input.xls ouput.csv